# Armadillo wrong field indexing

Tags: c++, armadillo

I need to build a 3d cube of (R,G,B) pixels such that the values of R,G and B are equal to their indexes in the cube.

For instance at Cube[0,0,0] I should find the pixel (0,0,0) which is black and at Cube[255,255,255] the pixel value should be (255,255,255) or white.
In practice, the cube should store all the possible colors in 8 bits.

To accomplish that I have seen that the Armadillo library has the `field` type.
So I thought it reasonable to store each pixel in a `Col<size_t>` and to build and fill a 3D field from them, like this:

```
#include <armadillo>
typedef arma::Col<size_t> Pixel;
int nc = 256;

arma::field<Pixel> my_cube(nc, nc, nc);

for (size_t i = 0; i < nc; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < nc; j++)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < nc; k++)
        {
            Pixel px = { i, j, k };
            my_cube[i, j, k] = px;
            my_cube[i, j, k].print();  // here I get the correct value for (i,j,k)
        }

    }
}

my_cube[0, 0, 0].print();  // here I get (255,255,0) instead of (0,0,0)
// If I try my_cube(0,0,0).print() or my_cube.at(0,0,0).print()
// I get the same wrong result for the (0,0,0) pixel and 
// [matrix(0x1)] for different values of the indices.
```

However, when I try to access an element after the outer loop, I get the wrong result (see code above).

Can someone explain this behaviour? What am I missing to retrieve the correct values after the for loops?

I could have easily done the task with OpenCV but the code I'm writing is part of a project in which I can't use it.

I am using Armadillo 9.900 and Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` only works with a single argument. Therefore, `my_cube[i, j, k]` is wrong.

You mention that `my_cube(0,0,0).print()` or `my_cube.at(0,0,0).print()` also shown the same problem, but they are doing the right thing. However, you also need to use either of them during the assignment. Change `my_cube[i, j, k] = px;` to `my_cube(i, j, k) = px;` or `my_cube.at(i, j, k) = px;` and it will work.